# How do I get the public IP address when starting a GSM modem in server mode?

Tags: server, ip-address, gsm, at-command, sim800

I have a **SIM800C** GSM module that I want to use to make a server. I am really confused about knowing the public IP address. In order to make people to connect to any server is that they need the correct public IP address and the correct port, and of course the correct protocol (TCP, HTTP and so on..).

There is already a command to get the local IP address (`AT+CIFSR`); in case I make a server and I want to let my friends connect to it, I need the public IP address. How do I get it?

I searched on the internet but found nothing.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, Thank you. You can post this as an answer, and I will mark it as a solution. Better than leaving the question unanswered. But could you please explain more about the "push SMS". But let me ask you, do you mean by "push SMS" is using SMS messages as a way to communicate without using the PDP context? Thank you again..

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer after expanding them. I tried also to explain the "push SMS" thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AT+CIFSR` (as well as the standard command `AT+CGPADDR`) returns your IP as soon as you activate the PDP context. Unfortunately, if it is public or not depends on your operator. In fact, due to the need to face the *IPv4 address exhaustion* they often perform a *Network Address Translation* (NAT) that will actually provide a local IP to your device.

As a consequence, your device won't be reachable for communications that are not device-initiated, and you won't able to create a public server at all.

So, that's not *a public IP opposed to a local IP*: there's just the IP you obtain from the network. If doesn't perform NAT, then the IP you obtain with `AT+CIFSR` will be the public one.

---

### Design work-around

Usually the *NATted* IP limitation is faced with a design trick

1. A *wake-up* SMS is sent to the device hosting the server. The SMS can either be a *basic* one (just text containing data relevant to the application) or a special SMS type (Wap Push notifications).
2. As soon it receives the SMS, the device starts the server and sends some data to the remote peer
3. This will result in a device initiated communication, so from the network side the NAT will be opened and the device will be temporarily public.
4. After a certain inactivity time (operator dependent) the NAT will be closed again

---

### "Commercial" solution

If the design solution is not feasible, there's another option involving the purchase of special (and more expensive...) SIMs specific for M2M and IOT applications:

1. SIMs which will always obtain a public IP
2. SIMs which will always obtain a public **fixed** IP